# Import contact list from twitter

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

I am developing android application and want to use twitter log in and import contact list from   twitter. i am using twitter4j library and i can log into twitter via android app.i want to   know how to import contact list from .

Comment: do u want followers and following names ?

Comment: actually i need followers list with their names

Comment: i have down but using jtwitter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have all the followers Ids from below api,

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=patel
```

And than you can get info of all that followers from this api,

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json?user_id=401702563,1013369934,....
```

But, these apis will be deprecated by Twitter from March,2013. Rather this, You can try Twitter api version 1.1.

Refer this [link](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1) for that.